# libpangocairo-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: cairo_has_show_text_glyphs error

Tags: debian, libraries

I am using Debian Squeeze and I wanted to install Gimp 2.8. I installed a lot of packages dependencies for Gimp but I could not successfully complete the install of the Gimp package

When installing the Gimp dependent packages, I think I broke a necessary package because now I am getting  the following error when I try to start `thunar`, `gedit` and more.

```
symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: cairo_has_show_text_glyphs
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've installed a version of `libpangocairo-1.0.so.0` in `/usr/local/lib` that's incompatible with the version in `/usr/lib` (probably because they're compiled against different versions of the libraries they depend on).

If you are no longer using the Gnome libraries in `/usr/local/lib`, remove them. If you're using them for applications that you've installed in `/usr/local/bin`, either recompile those applications against the library versions in Debian, or move the libraries outside the standard library path and use a shell script like this to launch the Gnome applications in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gnome-extra-libraries
exec /usr/local/bin/locally-installed-gnome-application.bin
```

Move `libpangocairo-1.0.so.0` and its companions to `/usr/local/lib/gnome-extra-libraries` and move `/usr/local/bin/locally-installed-gnome-application` to `/usr/local/bin/locally-installed-gnome-application.bin`.

Comment: I am using xfce4 instead of gnome.I am not sure that I am using gnome libraries.Most of the files in /usr/local/lib related with dependent libraries of gimp.

Comment: The problem resolved when remove files in /usr/local/lib :) . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of `libpango1.0-0` is causing problems, try to switch back to the correct one for squeeze, if possible.

```
dlocate libpangocairo-1.0.so.0

libpango1.0-0: /usr/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.2800.3

apt-cache policy libpango1.0-0

libpango1.0-0:
  Installed: 1.28.3-1+squeeze2
  Candidate: 1.28.3-1+squeeze2
  Version table:
     1.30.0-1 0
         50 http://debian.csail.mit.edu/debian/ testing/main i386 Packages
         50 http://debian.csail.mit.edu/debian/ unstable/main i386 Packages
 *** 1.28.3-1+squeeze2 0
        500 http://debian.csail.mit.edu/debian/ squeeze/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

What version does `apt-cache policy` show you for `libpango1.0-0`?

Try

```
apt-get install libpango1.0-0/stable
```

If apt complains about dependencies, try adding them to the command line, as packagename/stable. I don't know if this will work, but it is a reasonable first step.

To backport gimp 2.8 may not be so easy. I suggest you post that as a separate question.

Comment: dlocate libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 giving two result(libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 and libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.2800.3). libpango version output is [http://pastebin.com/iWfXce5P](http://pastebin.com/iWfXce5P)

Comment: @mesuutt: Just add the info to your answer. `libpangocairo-1.0.so.0` and `libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.2800.3` are not packages. Paste the output of `dpkg -S libpangocairo-1.0.so.0`. It can't correspond to more than one package. You have the squeeze version of libpango1.0-0 installed so that is not itself the problem. Maybe get apt-show-versions to give you a list of installed packages not in stable? You probably don't want to post that - it would be too long.

Comment: Hang on, I just realised your error message is `/usr/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0`. Why is it looking in `/usr/local`? Did you compile and install some package locally?

Comment: I dont know why but dlocate and dpkg -S gives same output.[dpkg  and dlocate command output](http://pastebin.com/fxnYEiLZ)

Comment: I dont know why is it looking in /usr/local, I realize now. What are you mean with compile and install locally ?

Comment: @mesuutt: Again, just put the output in your question. Are all the packages you installed binary packages from the Debian archives, or did you install some packages from source? This is *not* recommended if Debian packages are available.

Comment: @mesuutt: you are misinterpreting the output of `dpkg -S` and `dlocate`. The package name is on the left; the file name is on the right. The files in question all belong to `libpango1.0-0`.

Comment: same problem on debian 10, solved by `apt-get install libpango1.0-0`