# How to install gimp 2.8 on Debian Squeeze?

Tags: debian, software-installation, gimp

Gimp 2.8 comes with a lot dependencies.
How to install gimp 2.8 with dependencies on Debian Squeeze ?

Comment: I think you are missing libgegl-0.2-0 and libbabl-0.1-0. You can install them via apt-get and afterwards you can grab gimp too by the same means...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no gimp2.8 in backports, therefore the easiest way is to add testing repositories to your machine:

```
echo "deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ testing main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then you need to configure apt pin priorities to make testing version as additional to prevent distributive upgrade.
For that do

```
echo "Package: *
      Pin: release a=stable
      Pin-Priority: 700

      Package: *
      Pin: release a=testing
      Pin-Priority: 650" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/preferences
```

After that you can update you packages list:

```
aptitude update
```

And install gimp2.8 from testing with:

```
aptitude -t testing install gimp
```

It will resolve dependencies and upgrade all necessary packages automatically.

Also you can backport gimp yourself, but it is much harder (:

Comment: After first gimp install attempt I encountered [a problem](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39332/libpangocairo-1-0-so-0) and I tried this on VirtualBox :). During process a lot of packages removed.After process complete  I encounter another X problem( [Xorg.0.log file](http://pastebin.com/T3bnpkiV) ).What is the my misfortune :)

Comment: I wonder where am I doing wrong ?.There is another method to install gimp? or why occur this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't too tight on disk space, the easiest way to combine a stable system with the latest versions of a few applications is to run Debian stable, and maintain an installation of Debian unstable or testing in a [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot).

For a guide to setting up a Debian-like distribution in a chroot, see [How do I run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit Debian/Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-ubuntu) (the schroot section). The guide is written for 32-bit Ubuntu inside 64-bit Ubuntu, but applies equally to unstable inside stable and to Debian.

Set up the schroot, and install Gimp inside it. You can make a wrapper outside the chroot to run a chrooted Gimp. Put this file as `/usr/local/bin/gimp` (assuming you installed a wheezy chroot in `/wheezy`):

```
#!/bin/sh
exec schroot -c /wheezy gimp
```

Answer (score -1):

```
wget ftp://ftp.gimp.org/pub/gimp/v2.8/gimp-2.8.0.tar.bz2
mv gimp-2.8.0.tar.bz2 /tmp/
tar xf gimp-2.8.0.tar.bz2
cd gimp-2.8.0/
./configure
make all && make install
```

Comment: Gimp comes with a lot dependencies.Gimp cant install alone on Squeeze.

Comment: That's really bad idea to compile something on binary distributive with excellent package manager. In the worst case you can use `checkinstall`, but never use `make install`. btw building deb packages is also pretty easy.

Comment: building a package in binary distro should be normal for linux user.  
never use make install? can you tell why not to use it?

Comment: @ochach yes you can, but there is no dependency checker and update manager for this package... if really you love you squeeze and only want gimp 2.8 you can make it. but its better to find another way ;)

Comment: @Efazati thx, i get it.